# Turning a List to a list of list to avoid an Attribute error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that I am trying to run through a function that checks to find invalid values from a JSON called valid, I am getting an attribute error list object has no attribute apply.

```
col_list=[col for col in df]
key=list(valid.keys())
for k in key:
    if k not in col_list:
        key.remove(k)

print(key)
#Key values ['industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'country', 'state']

mask = key.apply(lambda c: c.isin(valid[c.name]))
key.mask(mask|key.eq(' ')).stack()
for err_i, (r, v) in enumerate(key.mask(mask|key.eq(' ')).stack().iteritems()):
    errors[filename][err_i] = {"row": r[0],
                               "column": r[1],
                               "message": v + " is invalid check column " + r[1] + ' and replace with a standard value'}
```

I have found that if i make a list of list and call something like instead of key

```
df1=[['industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'country', 'state']]
```

this works but once its just a regular list it doesn't. how do I make a list call to be a list of list so the variable key is able to use apply?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to transform a list into a list of lists, just add

```py
key = [key]
```

You could also try using map instead of apply if you don't want to have to transform your list into a list of lists

Comment: what would it look like if i wanted to use map?, Even when I have tried to use
```
key=[key]
```
I still get an attribute error

Comment: ```key = list(map(your_lambda_func, key)```